# "Invalid SQL data type" error when TVP data has None in first row

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I get this error when I try to start a Stored Procedure through pyodbc in an SQL Server database with a TVP and a column has a None value.

> [HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)

Is there any way to indicate to pyodbc the datatype of the column or do I have to give up in TVP's?

This is what I'm trying:

```py
cursor.execute("{CALL dbo.stored_procedure (?, ?)}", (None, tvp_data))
```

First variable I don't care about, second one is my TVP. Everything works fine as long as there is no None in a column in the TVP itself, but if there is, I get the error.

Comment: How are you creating `tvp_data`? Are you following the examples https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/969ea2c42712036d473fab5d4db715452580c6d3/tests3/sqlservertests.py#L1647

Comment: I am using a list of tuples for example: tvp_data = [(value1,value2),(value3,value4)]  but if value1 is None instead of something else like 'whatever' it doesnt work

Comment: Provide us with a full [mre]; the above is not enough for us to replicate the issue without guess work.

Comment: related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1229

Comment: @DaleK - `{CALL …}` is an ODBC function for calling SPs in a database-agnostic way. It maps to `EXEC` for mssql.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of the parameter metadata discovery as discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/596#issuecomment-520024907) and [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1229). Workarounds include:

Option 1. Sort your TVP data so the first row contains no `None` values.

Option 2. Use `OPENJSON()` in an anonymous code block and pass your TVP data as a JSON string.

```py
tvp_data = [(1, None), (2, "Bravo")]
tvp_json = [dict(zip(["id", "txt"], row)) for row in tvp_data]

sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tvp dbo.issue_1229_table_type;
INSERT INTO @tvp (id, txt)
SELECT id, txt FROM OPENJSON(?)
WITH (
    id int '$.id',
    txt nvarchar(50) '$.txt'
);
EXEC issue_1229_sp @tvp
"""
results = crsr.execute(sql, json.dumps(tvp_json, default=str)).fetchall()
print(results)
# [(1, None), (2, 'Bravo')]
```

(Example copied from my own GitHub comment [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1229#issuecomment-1584984799).)